# How can I open a post by clicking where the entire post will be displayed one by one (title and body of the post) in jquery?

Tags: jquery, json, api, post, title

By clicking on title I need to show  the entire post  (title and body of the post)

Here is my code:

```
          console.log(chunk,numberOfItems, limitPerPage, totalPages,index);
          $.each(result, function (index, item) {
              $("#loop").append("<div  class='card bg-info'>User ID:"+item.userId +
                                          "<div class='card-header'>ID:"+item.id+"</div>" +
                                          "<div class='card-body'>" +
                                            "<h5 class='card-title'>"+item.title+"</h5>" +
                                            "<p class='card-text'>"+(item.body).slice(0, 100)+"</p>" + "</div>" +
                                            "</div>");


                $(document).ready(function(){
                $(".card-title").click(function(e){     
                e.preventDefault();
                 var url = $(this).attr('href');
                 window.open('#loop');
               });
             });
           });
        }
    });

    

});
```

Comment: Can you edit your question and add a snippet where your problem is illustrated? It would be easier to play around with it then and solve it.